# i keep getting "function name must be a string" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a site using laravel, and I got this error when trying to upload an image. I'm a beginner so, can I get some help?

```
$user = Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request('name');
    $user->update();
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = $request->name . '-' . $user->id . '.jpg';
```

Comment: Which error? Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Function name must be a string"
This is the message from XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

$user->name = $request('name');
$request is variable not func because of $

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Your are using variable like function. Later you accessed propery of this variable called name by typing $request->name,so change $request(‚name’) to $request->name

Comment: Thanks, bro. got it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't follow the [naming rules](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) in PHP : $request('name') .

I guess you were going to use $request->get('name')

For Uploading image you can use following code, Although I prefer using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)

```
//Auth::loginUsingId(1); #You can test your code without a real login

$data = $request->only(['name']);

    if (request()->hasFile('image')) {
        $file = request()->file('image');
        $fileName = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/'); //// I assume you have a folder named images in public.
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

        $data['avatar'] = $destinationPath.$fileName; // I assume you have a field named avatar in users table.
    }

    return $data; // Try this line for a better understanding then comment it


    Auth::user()->update($data);
```